# Problem with filling virtual properties on Entity Framework by configuring their relations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, code-first

I've got a problem with some virtual marked properties, there's some one-many relations and I want to have it configurated manually.
I'd like to focus only on relation one landlord - many offers.

The problem is, when I'm adding new offer (even from endpoint, not seed), it won't be added to landlord's collection, for example from code offer1 to landlord1. And for offer1, the virtual property IdLandlordNavigation won't be filled by landlord1.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Offer class body

```cs
public class Offer
    {
        public Offer()
        {
            Rentals = new HashSet<Rental>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public double Surface { get; set; }

        public int IdLandlord { get; set; }

        public virtual Landlord IdLandlordNavigation { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Rental> Rentals { get; set; }
    }
```

Offer EF Configuration

```cs
public class OfferEFConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Offer>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Offer> builder)
        {
            builder.HasOne(d => d.IdLandlordNavigation)
                .WithMany(d => d.Offers)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdLandlord)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("Landlord_Offer")
                .IsRequired();

            var offers = new List<Offer>();

            offers.Add(new Offer()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Offer1",
                Description = "Offer1Desc",
                Surface = 10.5d,
                IdLandlord = 1
            });
            //more offers
            builder.HasData(offers);
        }
    }
```

Landlord class body

```cs
public class Landlord : User
    {
        public Landlord()
        {
            Offers = new HashSet<Offer>();
        }
        public virtual ICollection<Offer> Offers { get; set; }
    }
```

Landlord EF Configuration

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Landlord> builder)
        {
            var landlords = new List<Landlord>();

            byte[] salt = new byte[128 / 8];
            using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
            {
                rng.GetBytes(salt);
            }
            landlords.Add(new Landlord()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Email = "landlord1@mail.com",
                FirstName = "Landlord1Name",
                LastName = "Landlord1LastName",
                Password = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
                    password: "password1",
                    salt: salt,
                    prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
                    iterationCount: 10,
                    numBytesRequested: 256 / 8)),
                RefreshToken = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                RefreshTokenExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),
                Salt = Convert.ToBase64String(salt),
                IsVerified = true,
                PhoneNumber = "123456789"
            });
            //more landlords
            builder.HasData(landlords);
        }
```

Comment: Either lazy loading will have to be enabled or you'll have to use the .Include method in your LINQ query